# Aggregate results into Named Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, aggregate

I have a named type defined - Totals with several Properties.

Right now I have some totals coming back into an anonymous type:

```
Dim filteredList = Aggregate ts As Totals In empTot 
Where ts.Status = "Active" Into  
Tot1= Sum(ts.Tot1), Tot2= Sum(ts.Tot2)
```

I want to use a named type in the same way that I can do that in a select:

```
Dim londonCusts5 = From cust In customers
                   Where cust.City = "London"
                   Order By cust.Name Ascending
                   Select New NamePhone With
                   {
                       .Name = cust.Name,
                       .Phone = cust.Phone
                   }
```

Select example taken from [MSDN Linq Docs - Select Data Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384504.aspx)

Is this possible in the Aggregate statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible with the LINQ syntax you are using. However, using the LINQ extension methods on `IEnumerable`, you can accomplish this.

Example:

```
Class MyTotal
    Public Property Tot1 As Integer
    Public Property Tot2 As Integer
End Class

Dim filteredList = empTot.Where(Function(ts) ts.Status = "Active") _
                   .Aggregate(New MyTotal(), Function(mt, value)
                                                 mt.Tot1 += value.Tot1
                                                 mt.Tot2 += value.Tot2
                                                 Return mt
                                             End Function)
```